# get access textbox text from another form textbox text (multiple form)

Tags: c#, textbox, sms

currently i am doing sms function by using window mobile standard 6.
i have multiple form, up to 4 window form.
and at the last form, i wish to collect all the data that already key in in previous form textbox text, and send message to people.

example:

```
in form 1: textBox1. text
form 2: textBox1.text
```

......
at the SMS form coding like:

```
{
SmsMessage messageFromForm1TextBox1 = new SmsMessage (textBox1.Text, "this text get from 1 textBox1")
messageFromForm1TextBox1.Send();

SmsMessage messageFromForm2TextBox1 = new SmsMessage (textBox1.Text, "this text get from 2 textBox1")
messageFromForm1TextBox1.Send();
}
```

i wish to know how to get another form textBox.text , adding to my sms contain at SMS form.
kindly advice.
thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a class to hold the data from these forms and store it in a shared instance somewhere.

For example, the class to hold the values:

```
public class MyValues
{
    public string Form1TextBox1 { get; set; }
    public string Form2TextBox1 { get; set; }
}
```

and the static class to hold the active instance:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public static MyValues CurrentInstance {get; set;}
}
```

finally, in form1, you will need to create the new instance:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ViewModel.CurrentInstance = new MyValues();
    }
}
```

then, in your command to move to the next form, you can save the values in the instance:

```
        ViewModel.CurrentInstance.Form1TextBox1 = TextBox1.Text;
```

Comment: hi thx reply
i had follow the step that you had post,
but it show me nothing at the end.
i think something wrong with me.
where can i add "ViewModel.CurrentInstance.Form1TextBox1 = TextBox1.Text;" that you provide me? to my codding bellow?
in my sms window form i don't have any textBox
it only have 1 button name send, when i click the button, it will run bellow coding:

{
SmsMessage messageFromForm1TextBox1 = new SmsMessage (textBox1.Text, "this text get from 1 textBox1")
messageFromForm1TextBox1.Send();
}

Comment: @user1066999: yes, you would put that code in your send button. You can change the names of the fields to match what is in your program, I was just providing an example.